# Mathematical approach to derive function

Tags: python, algorithm, function, math

I have a data sheet which lots of data, all spread out over several columns. The data extracted below will show the problem I am facing:

[image: data sheet example]

This table represents changes in an inventory system.  Positive amount changes mean new items were added to the inventory and the **item price** for these are known. The item price equals the import purchasing price.

When an order was made, the corresponding amount change is negative, and the price is unknown. The algorithm should fill in these unknown prices.

The items that have been the longest in stock should be sold first, at the same price they were bought. Once such a batch is depleted, the next batch should be used to determine the price of a sale.

For example, in row 3, 3 items were sold, and we are left with 9 items in the inventory. We know by looking at the data, that the single item price for these 3 products is 49.55.  But of course, it starts to get more complicated as items have been added and subtracted:

Take the last row. At that moment, the first batch (at 49.55) has already been sold completely. The next batch (at 48.25) only has 2 items -- not enough for the 7 that are ordered. The batch after that (at 47.23) has enough to provide for the remaining 5 items. The price per item should thus be a weighted average of these two prices.

So now, I am looking for a function or algorithm to determine the item price that should be used when an order was placed.

Comment: What will be the logic for determining the price? It is not clear from the question.

Comment: No, your issue is not clear at all. You wrote "_algorithm to determine the item price that should be used when an order was placed_" but you don't specify any constraints that should be met by the calculated price. So why can't you just use `0` for each row? Or the first buy price? Or the price of the most recent buy? I suspect that all those choices are not what you want because there are some additional implicit constraints in your head. Unfortunately we can't read them from there. So put the constraints explicitly in the question!

Comment: The logic is what I am looking for.  Example on row 3: we should take into account the item price from row 1, because those 3 items basically come from that batch of items.  On row 4, 3 more items are taken away, so that will also be the item price from row 1.  And so on... So once all the items from inventory 1 have been used up, we should take into account the item price from batch 2, etc.

Comment: I edited your question, adding some more explanation based on your last comment. Could you check that this reflects what you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some python code that implements a [FIFO algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_and_LIFO_accounting) on selling items from stock:

```
stock = [
    { "before":  0, "change": 10, "price": 49.55 },  
    { "before": 10, "change":  2, "price": 48.25 },  
    { "before": 12, "change": -3, "price": None  },  
    { "before":  9, "change": -3, "price": None  },  
    { "before":  6, "change": -4, "price": None  },  
    { "before":  2, "change":  8, "price": 47.23 },  
    { "before": 10, "change": -7, "price": None  },  
]

queue = []
for line in stock:
    if line["change"] > 0:
        queue.append({ "stock": line["change"], "price": line["price"] })
    else:
        # calculate price from queue
        count = -line["change"]
        totalPrice = 0
        while count > 0:
            take = min(count, queue[0]["stock"])
            totalPrice += take * queue[0]["price"]
            count -= take
            queue[0]["stock"] -= take
            if not queue[0]["stock"]:
                queue.pop(0) # no more items in this "batch": remove it
        # Calculate an average price. Because of rounding, cents may not add up
        line["price"] = round(totalPrice / -line["change"], 2)

# output result
for line in stock:
    print(line)
```

Output is:

```
{'before':  0, 'change': 10, 'price': 49.55}
{'before': 10, 'change':  2, 'price': 48.25}
{'before': 12, 'change': -3, 'price': 49.55}
{'before':  9, 'change': -3, 'price': 49.55}
{'before':  6, 'change': -4, 'price': 49.55}
{'before':  2, 'change':  8, 'price': 47.23}
{'before': 10, 'change': -7, 'price': 47.52}
```

Note that some prices (the last one in the example) are weighted averages of prices from two or more batches. In that case the real average may have more decimal digits, which need to be rounded away. This will then lead to an amount balance that is not exactly 0 after all has been sold.

Comment: This is exactly the answer to my problem! And the weighted averages will do perfectly for my problem, I am not after exact numbers, but close to a proper estimate.  I will modify it to my needs and give it a try! Thanks!